How to writting /etc/hosts file to assign domain with fixed ip for multiple network interface?
I have many tasks with need to post/get http requests with a host, fstream.binance.com.
This url mapped to many phyical server, each has it own ip, for example.
nslookup fstream.binance.com

Server:     172.31.0.2
Address:    172.31.0.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   fstream.binance.com
Address: 13.112.185.191
Name:   fstream.binance.com
Address: 52.194.25.186

As you can see, this url linked with two ip, ip1: 13.112.185.191 and ip2:52.194.25.186
My server also has two network interface, each interface has it own ip, which is ni1 : 13.112.182.3 and ni2: 52.194.25.7
From the ip address, we can known, ni1 is close with ip1 and ni2 is close with ip2.
For only one network interface, I know i can add this in /etc/hosts:
13.112.182.3 fstream.binance.com

In this setting, It's good for ni1, but for ni2, the server will be not close (slow)
So, how can i bind fstream.binance.com with ip1 in ni1, and ip2 with ni2?
I think /etc/hosts can just bind fstream.binance.com with one fixed ip?
Thanks

It sounds like you should be looking at adding custom routes.
Linux uses routing rules to decide the next hop for outbound traffic. In the most common situation, your system will have routes for any directly connected networks and a default route for destinations to which your system is not directly connected.
In this case, you want to add some additional rules such that traffic to the two different binance addresses egresses from different interfaces. Presumably your two nics have different gateway addresses, so maybe something like:
ip route add 13.112.185.191 via <nic1 gateway address>
ip route add 52.194.25.186 via <nic2 gateway address>

Persistently configuring routes like this varies from distribution to distribution; see your distribution documentation for more information.
